# Magento 2.4.3-p3 upgrading to 2.4.5 - Composer, Symfony error

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento-upgrade

I recently updated Magento from 2.4.3-p3 to 2.4.5.

Everything went well but i have few errors:

**/usr/local/bin/php81 -d memory_limit=-1M /usr/local/bin/composer.phar update**

```
Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\CompositeRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/CompositeRepository.php:180
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:675
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:732
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FilterIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FilterIterator.php:30
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FileTypeFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FileTypeFilterIterator.php:42
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getChildren(): RecursiveDirectoryIterator, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:85
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with FilesystemIterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:113
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::current() should either be compatible with FilesystemIterator::current(): SplFileInfo|FilesystemIterator|string, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:65
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php:55
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::hasChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::hasChildren(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php:71
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::getChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::getChildren(): ?RecursiveIterator, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php:76
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FilterIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FilterIterator.php:30
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FilenameFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FilenameFilterIterator.php:28
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\PathFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/PathFilterIterator.php:27
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
In Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterV2::onPrePoolCreate
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:76
Updating dependencies
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php:116
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSet::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php:101
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\Decisions::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php:155
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\Decisions::next() should either be compatible with Iterator::next(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php:165
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\Decisions::key() should either be compatible with Iterator::key(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php:160
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\Decisions::valid() should either be compatible with Iterator::valid(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php:170
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\Decisions::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php:150
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\Decisions::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php:145
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetIterator::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetIterator.php:36
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetIterator::next() should either be compatible with Iterator::next(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetIterator.php:46
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetIterator::key() should either be compatible with Iterator::key(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetIterator.php:41
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetIterator::valid() should either be compatible with Iterator::valid(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetIterator.php:89
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetIterator.php:70
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.
Package php-cs-fixer/diff is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
122 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\DepthRangeFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/DepthRangeFilterIterator.php:41
PHP CodeSniffer Config installed_paths set to ../../magento/magento-coding-standard,../../phpcompatibility/php-compatibility
```

Also i got few php_errorlog:

**public_html/php_errorlog:**

```
[25-Aug-2022 12:43:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Imagick::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
[25-Aug-2022 12:43:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Imagick::next() should either be compatible with Iterator::next(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
[25-Aug-2022 12:43:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Imagick::key() should either be compatible with Iterator::key(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
[25-Aug-2022 12:43:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Imagick::valid() should either be compatible with Iterator::valid(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
[25-Aug-2022 12:43:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Imagick::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
[25-Aug-2022 12:43:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of ImagickPixelIterator::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
[25-Aug-2022 12:43:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of ImagickPixelIterator::next() should either be compatible with Iterator::next(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
[25-Aug-2022 12:43:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of ImagickPixelIterator::key() should either be compatible with Iterator::key(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
[25-Aug-2022 12:43:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of ImagickPixelIterator::valid() should either be compatible with Iterator::valid(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
[25-Aug-2022 12:43:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of ImagickPixelIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in Unknown on line 0
[25-Aug-2022 14:43:00 Europe/Zagreb] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112
```

**public_html/var/report/3f7cab26....:**

```
{"0":"Deprecated Functionality: preg_match(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($subject) of type string is deprecated in \/public_html\/vendor\/amasty\/module-page-speed-tools\/Lib\/MobileDetect.php on line 1267","1":"#1 preg_match() called at [vendor\/amasty\/module-page-speed-tools\/Lib\/MobileDetect.php:1267]\n#2 Amasty\\PageSpeedTools\\Lib\\MobileDetect->match() called at [vendor\/amasty\/module-page-speed-tools\/Lib\/MobileDetect.php:1216]\n#3 Amasty\\PageSpeedTools\\Lib\\MobileDetect->isTablet() called at [vendor\/amasty\/module-page-speed-tools\/Model\/DeviceDetect.php:110]\n#4 Amasty\\PageSpeedTools\\Model\\DeviceDetect->detectDevice() called at [vendor\/amasty\/module-page-speed-tools\/Model\/DeviceDetect.php:86]\n#5 Amasty\\PageSpeedTools\\Model\\DeviceDetect->getDeviceParams() called at [vendor\/amasty\/module-page-speed-tools\/Model\/DeviceDetect.php:96]\n#6 Amasty\\PageSpeedTools\\Model\\DeviceDetect->getDeviceType() called at [vendor\/amasty\/module-lazy-load\/Plugin\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Context.php:43]\n#7 Amasty\\LazyLoad\\Plugin\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Context->beforeGetVaryString() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:121]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Context\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#9 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Context\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Context\/Interceptor.php:59]\n#10 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Context\\Interceptor->getVaryString() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/PageCache\/Identifier.php:57]\n#11 Magento\\Framework\\App\\PageCache\\Identifier->getValue() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#12 Magento\\Framework\\App\\PageCache\\Identifier\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#13 Magento\\Framework\\App\\PageCache\\Identifier\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#14 Magento\\Framework\\App\\PageCache\\Identifier\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/PageCache\/Identifier\/Interceptor.php:23]\n#15 Magento\\Framework\\App\\PageCache\\Identifier\\Interceptor->getValue() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/PageCache\/Kernel.php:112]\n#16 Magento\\Framework\\App\\PageCache\\Kernel->load() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]\n#17 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#18 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#19 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:23]\n#20 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:116]\n#21 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:264]\n#22 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub\/index.php:30]\n","url":"\/customer\/account\/create\/","script_name":"\/pub\/index.php","report_id":"3f7cab26179ab93d57289f24c3f88fe86a573d8121233c1cce8c037ca8483e13"}
```

If you need any more information, tell me and I'll attach it.

Thank you in advance for your help.
Best regards.

Comment: what is your composer version? you can check it by run `/usr/local/bin/php81 -d memory_limit=-1M /usr/local/bin/composer.phar -v`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update composer version and try again.

You can also download composer.phar in Magento root and run command from root folder like

cd magento_root

composer.phar update